# Compound of geometric and beta distribution

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables

Suppose random variable $X_p$ has geometric distribution $G(p)$ for each $0<p<1$. And $Y$ is a random variable with beta distribution $B(1/2,1/2)$. I need to find the compounded distribution of random variable $X$ defined by $X(s)=X_{Y(s)}(s), s\in S$.

I think here I should find $f_X (x)= \int_0^1 f_{X|Y}(x|y)f_Y(y)dy$, but I'm not sure if it is correct. Any hints?

Comment: It is correct if $f_{X\mid Y}(x\mid y)$ is a probabililty mass function of geometric distribution.

Comment: Thank you! Now I'm stuck at $\frac{p \Gamma(1)}{\Gamma(1/2)\Gamma(1/2)} \int_0^1  \frac{(1-p)^{y-1}}{y^{1/2}(1-y)^{1/2}}dy$. How should I proceed from here?

Comment: Where does $(1-p)^{y-1}$ come from? Write $f_{X\mid Y}(x\mid y)$.

Comment: is it $(1-y)^k y$?

Comment: Nearly. Should it depend on x rather than on k? And also check what variant of geometric distribution $G(p)$ is considered in the exercise: $p(1-p)^{k-1}, k\geq 1$ or. $p(1-p)^{k}, k\geq 0$. In comments above you used both variants simultaneously.